# linq query for anonymus types

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know how can we query an arraylist of anonymous type using linq

I have an arraylist of anonymus type

```
 var pairs = new ArrayList() { new { id = 1, name = "ram" },` new { id = 2, name = "ramesh" } };
```

I want to have something to work like below

```
    var query = from stud in pairs
                where stud.id==1
                select stud;
```

it doesn't work because anonymous type compiler can only get the type while compiling , how do we handle this , any ideas?

Comment: Why ArrayList? Is it requirement to use it?

Comment: Don't use an `ArrayList`, use a `List`, or simply an array.

Comment: Well `ArrayList` has been used because you cannot fulfil the generic parameter of `List<T>` when you are simply declaring a new one in-line. No idea why you'd want to do that with anonymous types. Change it from an `ArrayList` (which will give you `object`) into an array:  `pairs = new[] { new { ...`.

Comment: @Servy: a `List<OfWhat>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter A list of anonymous types.  One can create a method to construct a list given a number of items that leverages method type inference to create the list, or you can use the array creation syntax for inferring the type, calling `ToList` in the event that a list, and not array, is needed.

Comment: isn't that technically a dictionary?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: the code does not compile because you cannot select from an arraylist without specifying the type which is not posssible with anonymous types.

Comment: @Tim Yes I realised and amended my comment (a while ago), I had actually changed my code to use an array because I cannot stand looking at `ArrayList` :-)

Comment: @IsmailHawayel No.  What makes you think that?

Comment: @Servy looks like an array of key value pairs where the id is the key n the name is the value ?

Comment: @IsmailHawayel Oh, I see what you mean now.  That is possible; it's also possible that it's a unique identifier, such as a primary key in a database, but that is worth investigating.

Answer (score 7):

`ArrayList` is a very old part of .Net -- avoid using it. If you use an anonymous array, everything will work:

```
var pairs = new [] { new { id = 1, name = "ram" }, new { id = 2, name = "ramesh" } };
var query = from stud in pairs
            where stud.id == 1
            select stud;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type to resolve type at runtime:

```
   var query = from dynamic stud in pairs
               where stud.id == 1
               select stud;
```

NOTE: I suggest you to use generic collection or, event better - create nice named class to hold your data. Assume it should look like

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then create list of students and query this list

```
var students = new List<Student> {
      new Student { Id = 1, Name = "ram" },
      new Student { Id = 2, Name = "ramesh" }
    };
```

Comment: Of course doing this means you lose all compile time type safety, and also have a pretty noticeable performance cost of running the compiler for every single item in the list.

Comment: @Servy Compiler? The DLR does a lot of good caching. Although I usually wouldn't advocate it as a solution to a problem like this.

Comment: @sergey Thanks lot.. Iam looking for something which gets the type dynamically ,"dynamic" solves the prob...